# How can I import all my python files in multiple folder hierarchy into a single pyinstaller executable?

Tags: python, import, pyqt5, pyinstaller, executable

I am developing a PyQT based Windows Application. I have lot of folders with many python files. But when I try to create an executable with the pyinstaller python package,the dependencies of the files in the other folders could not be resolved.
For Simplicity, this is my folder structure

```
gui
    -gui.py
    -main.py
libs
    -testlibs.py
utility
    -folderstructure.py
```

I have used the command **pyinstaller main.py --onefile**
The problem is gui.py imports utility.folderstructure which couldnot be resolved after the exe is generated.

The exe is throwing execption that utility cannot be found.

I have added addition hook directory option. In that I have added a file named hook-gui.py with content hiddenimports=[".utility.folderstructure.*"]
Now my folderstructure is

```
gui
    -gui.py
    -main.py
    -hook-gui.py
libs
    -testlibs.py
utility
    -folderstructure.py
```

But while running the command **pyinstaller ----additional-hooks-dir=. main.py --onefile**

INFO: Loading module hook **hook-gui.py**...
WARNING: Hidden import **.utility.folderstructure.*** not found! 
This particular error pops up.

Could you tell where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would use a layout similar to:

```
-main.py
-gui
    -init.py
    -gui.py
    -hook-gui.py
-libs
    -init.py
    -testlibs.py
-utility
    -init.py
    -folderstructure.py
```

Pyinstaller has always found the modules for me in this style layout.

You're just going to have to adjust some imports.

Comment: Yes, i have added --path="< Import path > " while running the pyinstaller and it resolved my issue. Thanks.